# How to set file/folder permissions using Rsync from Windows to Linux

Tags: windows, permissions, rsync, chmod

I want to transfer lots of files/folders from Windows to Linux using Rsync. On linux server(destination), I want the file permission set to 644, and folder permission set to 755. If possible, I want the ownership set to root.root for all the files/folders. I have tried -p option, but it doesn't work. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Try `umask 022` before your copy.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can set the perms using the `--chmod` parameter e.g.

```
--chmod=Du=rwx,Dgo=rx,Fu=rw,Fog=r
```

will force the permissions to be set to 755 for `D`irectories and 644 for `F`iles.

Comment: Thanks. The folder seems change to 744(drwxr--r--). Anyway, I decide to change the permission after transfer.

Comment: The `--chmod` also accepts octal mode numbers, which in my opinion is easier to visualize the permission given: `--chmod=D2775,F664`

Comment: You can also use `--chmod o=rX` in order to automatically give folders the `x` flag, but omit it from files.

Comment: Do you need to specify `--perms` as well?

Comment: @OrangeDog Yes. The correct usage is: `--perms --chmod=Du=rwx,Dgo=rx,Fu=rw,Fog=r`

Answer (score 12):

The --chmod argument syntax mentioned in the above is not quite accurate. When you specify owner, group, or other, and don't precede it with a "D" or a "F", it will apply that to all types of files, and it will apply the last parameter it finds as the default. This would explain why your directories were coming out as 744, since the last parameter in the argument was og=r.

Try this instead:

```
--chmod=Du=rwx,Dgo=rx,Fu=rw,Fgo=r
```